Reading aid to Paul Auster's '4 3 2 1'
I am reading Paul Auster's 4 3 2 1, a novel that tells the life of a man in four variations (like a multiverse without interactions, or the movie Mr. Nobody). The first/zeroth chapter is the same, hence the family members he knows as a child are the same, but as the plots advance, differences are introduced. It is however not easy to keep track of who is alive in which story, as there as so many similarities.
Is there an online resource, a diagram perhaps, that shows the state/plot summary of each family member at the beginning chapter X, variant Y?

If your book is paperback, you could try reading with different colours of felt-tip markers. Just a thought.

@Lambie Hi! I don't like writing/highlighting in books, but I also don't see how this would help me remember which cousins are alive in a particular thread? Flipping back and forth and rereading all relevant information in the same color?

You choose a color for some kinds of text and others for other details.
